# Получить объект из массива объектов, являющегося полем документа

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-query

Есть коллекция `coll`, содержащая более одного документа, следующей схемы:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(someId),
    sourceId: someId,
    "objArr" : [
        {
            "fieldA" : someValue,
            "fieldB" : someValue
        },
        {
            "fieldA" : someValue,
            "fieldB" : someValue
        },
        ...etc
    ]
}
```

необходимо сделать выборку следующим образом: зная `sourceId`, получить значения полей `fieldA` и `fieldB` того одного объекта из массива `objArr`, где оба поля удовлетворят условиям, например `(fieldA <= С и fieldB >= С)` стандартными методами с использованием индексации, т.е. без использования `$where`, например.

дополнение: в реальной жизни это может выглядеть как задача определить есть ли у некой сущности в множестве заданых периодов, период в который входит нужная нам дата.

дополнение: Конечно, решение этой задачи на стороне бэкенда не составляет труда, так как документ по `sourceId` мы легко получаем целиком и всегда можем пробежаться по массиву и достать конкретный объект, но хотелось бы знать может ли mongoDB сразу вернуть то что нужно.

Или это концептуально не верно и либо это, действительно, необходимо делать на бэкенде, либо хранить данные в плоском виде, где не будет массива объектов как поля документа а каждый такой объект будет 2мя полями в документе, те для одного `sourceId` будет столько документов в коллекции сколько было объектов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если  массив содержит только один подходящий документ тогда самый лучший, с точки зрения производительности, вариант это простой [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) запрос. Но чтобы это сработало, необходимо использовать оператор [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) для фильтрации.

Конечно, оператор [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) ограничивает выбор из массива и возврашает только первый элемент, соответствующий запросу.

```
db.coll.find(
    { 
        "sourceId": sourceId, 
        "objArr": { 
            "$elemMatch": { 
                "fieldA": { "$lte": 3 }, 
                "fieldB": { "$gte": 5 } 
            } 
        }
    },
    { "$objArr.$": 1 }
)
```

---

Если в массиве есть много подходящих документов, которые соотвествуют запросу, чтобы выбрать из массива все елементы, вам необходимо испрльзовать метод [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Здесь у вас есть два варианта, которые зависят отверсии MongoDB. Сначала рассмотрим самый лучший вариант.

#### MongoDB 3.2+

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "sourceId": sourceId } },
    { "$project": { 
        "objArr": { 
            "$filter": { 
                "input": "$objArr", 
                "in": "ob", 
                "cond": { 
                    "$and": [ 
                        { "$lte": [ "$$obj.fieldA", 3 ] },
                        { "$gte": [ "$$obj.fieldB", 5 ] },
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

#### MongoDB 2.6+

```
db.collect.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "sourceId": sourceId } },
    { "$project": { 
        "objArr": { 
            "$setDifference": [ 
                { "$map": { 
                    "input": "$objArr",
                    "as": "obj",
                    "in": { 
                        "$cond":  [
                            { "$and": [ 
                                { "$lte": [ "$$obj.fieldA", 3 ] },
                                { "$gte": [ "$$obj.fieldB", 5 ] },
                            },
                            "$$obj",
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                },
                [ false ]
            ]
        }
    }}
])
```

#### Объяснение:

- Первый `aggregate()` запрос очень простой. Для фильтрации документов необходимо использовать оператор [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).
- Второй вариант требует большего пояснения: Здесь мы используем оператор [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) который используя оператор [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond) позволяет делать логическую обработку каждого элемента в массиве и возвращает элемент, когда условие принимает значение *true* и в противном случае `false`.
  Полученый массив, после выполнения `$map`, содержает несколько элементов которые равны `false` и чтобы избавить от них, используйте оператор [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/).

Answer (score 1):

Если допускаются агрегации то можно выполнить такой код:

```
db.table.aggregate([
  {$match:{_id:1}},
  {$unwind:"$coll"},
  {$match:{"coll.fieldA":{$gt:10},"coll.fieldB":{$lt:20}}},
  {$project:{"fieldA":"$coll.fieldA","fieldB":"$coll.fieldB"}}
])
```

Comment: да, это подходит, ушел читать документацию по aggregate.

Answer (score -1):

Как на счёт такого решения:

```js
let valueA, valueB;
let A = 5, B = 10;

YourCollectionName.findOne({sourceId: someValue}, function(err, exemplar){
  if (err) throw err;
  if (!exemplar) console.log('Not found');
  exemplar.objArr.map(function(obj){
    if(obj.fieldA < A && obj.fieldB > B){
      valueA = obj.fieldA;
      valueB = obj.fieldB;
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Данный код будет работать при условии, что схема была создада с помощью mongoose.Schema

Comment: по требованиям производительности использовать $where нельзя поэтому такого рода решение не подходит.scala+play.